# WAMP / Xamp Apache Server not Starting

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, wampserver

The other day my Wamp server stopped starting (server will not start). I uninstalled, reinstalled etc. I restored my computer back 4 days to where it ran fine. Then I ran Xampp server and had the exact same problem. To me this indicates a Windows problem. `HTTPD.exe` crashes every time it is initiated. I have shut off the firewall and antivirus to no avail.

running `netstat -o` in `cmd` gives me `127.0.0.1:31595` and higher ports. Port 80 is not in use and is clear.

**In Services** (wampapache) when I attempt to start the service I get

> error 1058, "The service cannot be enabled because it is either
>   diabled or has no enabled devices".

**Apache logs** gives me

> [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 10764:tid 2012] (OS 10022)An invalid argument
>   was supplied. : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening
>   socket, is IPv6 available?

**Event Viewer** gives me this

> Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.3.0, time stamp:
>   0x502f70a3
>        Faulting module name: nvLsp.dll, version: 2.2.0.7316, time stamp: 0x4a80a5fd
>        Exception code: 0xc00000fd
>        Fault offset: 0x0000c257
>        Faulting process id: 0x2390
>        Faulting application start time: 0x01cde46e3fdd7d20
>        Faulting application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
>        Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NetworkAccessManager\bin32\nvLsp.dll
>        Report Id: 7eee3b80-5061-11e2-886a-00248c1defca

This is Win 7 home premium, Wamp is 64 bit and Xampp is 32 bit. Both worked before. I have read other threads here but they apply mainly to XP.

EDIT One thing I have done if went into Nvidia network controller and disabled the first packet. This got Xampp(partially, server will stay green but still no localhost) to work but not Wamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this helped me getting it solved:

- Check if you can start apache as program, not service, but via command prompt!
  `httpd` or `httpd -e debug` for all possible error & debug messages
  If it won't start, it will probably tell you the reason (e.g. php or apache configuration error)
- If still not OK then install and run it as a service* via command prompt to see if there is anything else wrong.
  `httpd -k install`  and  `httpd -k start`
  Check output at command prompt, error.log and Windows System Event Viewer (Windows Logs/System)

For me this learned me that I had errors in my httpd.conf.
After a while I discovered it had something to do with my alias directory, probably permissions. Changing permissions on folder didn't help much (probably bc. I don't know which User the default service uses), but changing service to log on as my user (which is admin) did work.

* *Remove this service afterwards if you have xampp or wamp, or you'll have a double entry.*

Comment: After my Windows 10 upgrade, Apache stopped working and won't restart. I've tried dozens of suggestions, like changing ports, etc. The httpd -e debug generated many lines that had no meaning to me.  The httpd -k install generated - (OS 5) Access is denied. Failed to open the WinNT service manager.  The httpd -k start generated - [error] (OS2) The system cannot find the file specified. No installed service named Apache2.2  Of course, it doesn't say what is looking for a service named Apache 2.2 and I did not type that in. I'm stuck. Beware Windows 10 upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of times skype/gtalk desktop version is the reason to make the port 80 busy. This dont appears on the netstat for some reason, but try to quit this kind of programs and start again your server.

Comment: Dont have skype :(. and dont have any chat progs running.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turned out that the Apache service was disabled for some reason.

To fix it, run the command `services.msc` and set Apache as enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try "run as administrator". Somewhere in windows7, those settings are corrupted somehow, i guess.

Comment: Tried that :) Tried starting it separately. Even the config files are ok as compared to my second computer

Answer (score 0):

i once had this issue on windows 8 for wamp server. But i did get the solution.

1. firstly press the windows + R keys on your keyboard
2. then type services.msc
3. search and locate wampapache
4. right click and select properties
5. change startup type from manual to automatic
6. click apply and ok
7. do same for wampmysqld